# case when "both ... and ..." is used with the single form of the verb

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, clefts

[proofreadnow.com](https://www.proofreadnow.com/blog/bid/56305/Subjects-Joined-by-And):

> If the subject consists of two or more words that are connected by "*and*" or by "*both...and*", the subject is plural and requires a plural verb.

[forum.wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/what-vs-that.3344861/):

> *What **is** required is both talent and hard work*.  (pseudo-cleft sentence)
>
> *It is both talent and hard work that **are** required*. (it-cleft sentence) [...] "*it is*" is a mismatch for plural "*that are*", so it is wrong.
>
> *It is both talent and hard work that **is** required*. [...] is correct

On the one hand I understand something, but on the other, could you explain to me please the latter box contents the more understandable way?

---

So:

**1.** *It is both talent and hard work that **are** required*.

**2.** *It is both talent and hard work that **is** required*.

Why is **1.** not correct?

Why is **2.** correct?

---

Let's put "*both*" out:

**3.** *It is talent and hard work that **are** required*.

**4.** *It is talent and hard work that **is** required*.

Which of them is correct and why?

Thanks!